# How to prevent a function form executing multiple times in a row in JS?

Tags: javascript

*It works now.

I am trying to make `onEnter()` and `onSpace()` functions not execute **more then once in a row**. For example, if I call `onEnter()`, it should execute the function only the first time, any calls in a **row** afterwards *shouldn't execute*. This is the same for `onSpace()`.

The program should run in **an order** of `onEnter()` then `onSpace()` or vice versa, however, if one of the functions is repeated, it should just run it once.

If you run the code below, you can see the problem, press the "**Enter**" key to get the next question and press the "**Space**" bar to find the answer.

Thank you for taking the time to help, this is my first project after learning a bit of JavaScript, any tips on improving my code is much appreciated.

```js
const onEnter = () => {

  if (document.getElementById("answer").style.visibility="visible") {
     document.getElementById("answer").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
    
   let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 0);
    let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 0);

   let addition = x +  " + "  + y; 
    let answer = x + y;

   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = addition;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
  
  toggleQuestion();
};


const toggleQuestion = () => {

  let qTop = document.getElementById("question");
  qTop.classList.toggle("questionAlt")
};

const onSpace = () => {

  toggleQuestion();
  document.getElementById("answer").style.visibility="visible";
}


document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keyEnter() {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      onEnter();
  }  
});


document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keySpace() {

    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      onSpace();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 97.9%;
  width: 98.9%;
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(155, 163, 167);
  
}

#answer {
  visibility: hidden;
  
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#question {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15vw;
  left: 40.6vw;
  font-family: 'Knewave';
  font-size: 8vw;
  
}

.question1 {
  position: absolute;
  animation: qBottom;
  animation-duration:0.2s;
  transition: 0.18s;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 13vw;
}

@keyframes qBottom {
   0%  {bottom:0.01px;}
  100% {bottom: 13vw;}
}


#answer {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20%;
 font-family: 'Knewave';
 font-size: 5.8vw;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 
}


.questionAlt {
  position: absolute;
  animation: qTop;
  animation-duration:0.2s;
  transition: 0.18s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 20vw;
  top: -10vw;
}

@keyframes qTop {
   0%  {top:0.01px;}
  100% {top:-10vw;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Knewave' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="plusBackground">

<button onclick="keyEnter()"> Next Question </button>
<button for="generate" onclick="" onclick="keySpace()"> Reveal </button>

<h1 id="question"> 8 + 8 </h1>

<h2 id="answer"> 16 </h2>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you mean with _more then once in a row._?

Comment: It means the functions shouldn't work if it repeats itself.

Comment: Well, same question, what does it mean? Ever? if there is a call to another function in the middle?

Comment: The program should run in an order of onEnter() then onSpace() or vice versa, repeating that order. If that makes sense?

Comment: ah you mean reapeating indefinitly, see if my updated answer meets your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer to meet your updated question
Actually you dont need to register multiple eventlistener :

```js
let current;
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keyEnter() {

    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.keyCode != current) {
      console.log("Enter")
      current = event.keyCode;
    }  
    if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.keyCode != current) {
      console.log("space")
      current = event.keyCode;
    }
});
```

Comment: i declared current ath the top its intiliazed to undefined, this variable will keep track of the last key clicked (space or enter), so i compare it with the new click and check if its the same key clicked twice (if thats the case i ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "once in a row" but does [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) or the [`once` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) for addEventListener help get you to where you want to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can create some simple flag for that, i.e:

```
// Set flag to false
let entered = false;

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keyEnter() {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      // Check flag, if false, run function
      if(!entered) {
        // Set flag to true
        entered = true;
        // run your function once
        onEnter();
      }
  }  
});
```

Comment: while this answer works, it is not optimal because the event listener is still registred in the event loop and can lead to a memory leak if abused.

Comment: Well, it depends on your program) Maybe you running not only `onEnter` function with this `keydown` event, but you want only `onEnter` to run once. I.e you need to keep tracking `Enter` press for some other UI functionality

Answer (score 0):

I would use two global flag variables both initialized to true: okToRunEnter and okToRunSpace.

Each related function should return immediately if its associated global flag variables is false. If it passes that check,  it should set both flag variables to false. Right before exiting, the function should set the *other* flag variable to true.